# How to insert 2 users at a time in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to insert 2 users in sql. So, I put Identity-increment to 2. Now I am generating Ids 1,3,5 like that. and to add second user, I am using this :

```
SET   IDENTITY_INSERT tblTesting ON;
 INSERT    INTO            tblTesting((@@Identity + 1), 'def');
SET  IDENTITY_INSERT tblTesting OFF;
```

But this one is giving me error. How can I do this?

I am using this method, as I am registering two users at same time, second user has relationship with 1st user. So, whenever I use 1st user ID, I can retrieve 2nd user using ID+1. I preferred to have 2 columns where 2 tables are similar but second user table has reference to 1st table. What Should I do in this case?

Comment: "But this one is giving me error." --> Please post the error message.

Comment: Why you try to insert explicit values into `IDENTITY` column ?

Comment: If you're trying to create some relationship between rows based on the numeric values in the identity column, you're doing something wrong. Despite them being store in `int` (or similar) columns, you should treat `IDENTITY` values as opaque blobs without any meaning. You definitely shouldn't rely on the actual values, or display them to end users, etc.